# Limiting the Number of Rows Deletes in SQLITE DB

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Anyone know of a way to limit the number of rows deleted when using an sql DELETE statement?I just need to delete a row that holds a certain value one time instead of deleting every instance of the value.  It's my understanding that the LIMIT clause cannot be added to DELETE statements in SQLITE. Now,  I can't see a way to limit the number of rows deleted just using _id because I don't know what row _id will be deleted ahead of time; the rows are being deleted based on a value held in a variable and they could be anywhere in the DB. I hope this makes sense. Here's the delete statement:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM strategyTotal WHERE strategy_prices = (?)" ;
db.execSQL(sql, new Double[] {subtractedStrategyPrice });
```

Comment: How do you know which of the rows meeting the condition(s) you want to delete?

Comment: The variable subtractedStrategyPrice holds a Double value (i.e. 68.99). Wherever that value appears in the table, the DELETE statement, in its current form, will delete the row containing it in the strategy_prices column. The problem is I just need it to delete a single row, and, currently, it doesn't matter which row with the value is deleted, just as long it's only one.

Comment: K - my answer should get you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM strategyTotal WHERE _id IN (SELECT _id FROM strategyTotal WHERE strategy_prices = (?) LIMIT 1);" ;
db.execSQL(sql, new Double[] {subtractedStrategyPrice });
```

Comment: My feelings would be a bit warmer and fuzzier if I sae = (subquery) instead of in (subquery).  After all, the objective is to delete one row.

Comment: @DanBracuk - OK... You do know, though, that this will only update 1 record since the subquery limits it to 1.

Comment: @DanBracuk: Yes, that's the goal. I am keeping a running total in that table, and I need one instance of the old value to be deleted when an item is updated so that the new value can be added and then the sum of the column will be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
    delete from tablename where rowid in (
    select rowid from tablename condition LIMIT 1)
```

try above work around or you may need to enable `SQLITE ENABLE UPDATE DELETE LIMIT`
my query is just an example. replace it with your own query.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I went with the previous suggestion and it worked.